# Guessing number in set 1-100 with weighted questions.

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

It is needed to guess number from 1 to 100. I can ask questions and get answers:"yes" or "no". For the "yes"-answer I must pay one dollar, for the "no"-answer - two dollars. How many dollars should I have to guess my number exactly?

The obvious decision is to product upper bound of $log_2 100$ on 2(we always divide our set on two equal parts and expect the worst case).

But I think that it is not an optimal algorithm, may be it is better to divide my set at an another ratio than one to one because of not equal costs of questions. May be at a ration two to one.

Help to find the best solution please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suggestion:  try working things out for *smaller* numbers first.

Comment: I tried to do it for a set 1-10 and found that I can guess number with 5 dollars(first of all I divided my set on two sets 1-7 and 8-10 and i.e.) but I can not find regularity and extend my thinkings on a set 1-100.

Comment: When I do it for a set 1-10, I find it takes 6 dollars.  So unless I'm misunderstanding the problem (or made a mistake myself), there's something awry in your thinking.  If you edit the problem to show how you go about solving the smaller case, we'll have a better idea how to help you.

Comment: "How many dollars should I have to guess my number exactly" It's not clear if you want to find an strategy that optimizes the worst-case cost, or rather an average.

Comment: "Barry Cipra", I have recounted and found that I need 6 dollars. But It is not possible that the decision is so obvious, it is counted as not very simple task.

Comment: "leonbloy", I need to think about the worst case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of formalisation, let's mark the questions by $A_{i}, 1\leq i\leq n$. Let's note $P(A_{i})=x_{i}$ - probability to get an "yes" for $A_{i}$. The mean is $1 \cdot x_{i} + 2 \cdot (1-x_{i})=2-x_{i}$. The total price is $2 \cdot n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$ - an optimisation problem of $x_{i}$ and $n$. Particularly, $x_{1}=x_{2}=...=x_{n}=x$, then the price is $n \cdot (2 - x)$.

By dividing the set (and subsequent sub-sets) in $M:K$ ratio, we have 2 extreme cases:

- assume each question is about $M$ side and we hit "yes" always, $(\frac{M}{M+K})^{n} \cdot 100 \approx 1$ or $n \approx -\log_{\frac{M}{M+K}}100$ and the price is $\approx -\log_{\frac{M}{M+K}}100$, (because $x=1$) which is ascending by $y=\frac{M}{M+K}$ on $(0,1)$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-log_%7Bx%7D%28100%29. I.e. we tend to reduce M and increase K, so that we hit "yes" for smaller sub-sets.
- assume each question is about $M$ and we hit "no" always (as if the number is not in that side), so we will continue with the other side always, aka  $(1-\frac{M}{M+K})^{n} \cdot 100 \approx 1$ or $n \approx -\log_{\frac{K}{M+K}}100$ and the price is $\approx -2 \cdot\log_{\frac{K}{M+K}}100$, (because $x=0$) which is again ascending by $y=\frac{K}{M+K}$ in on $(0,1)$. I.e. we tend to reduce K and increase M, so that we hit "no" for larger sub-sets.

We end up with this "increase-reduce" $K$ and "increase-reduce" $M$ at the same time, which indicates (imho) 50:50 might be the best bet.